# Reduce Application Size

Tags: ios, iphone

In my last update my application size was 36 MB when i uploaded on app store. Then i added some pods files like Firebase Database ,storage and JSQMessagesViewController in my project after that when i uploaded my application its size increased and it become 101 MB. I'm shocked that how it is increased so and why? How can i reduced this size like about 40 MB? I have also used Bridge Header File in my project because firebase chat code is in swift and my project is in objective C.
[image]

Comment: You can reduce filesize by putting less stuff into the application. This is all the information i can give, because you did not include any more information.

Comment: The size on your filesystem might not correctly represent the size in the Appstore. Since this includes all the architecture and when installing only the supported architecture is downloaded. Also some debug information might be in this build. Are you using swift? Then the swift libraries are also included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export an archive to an ipa from the organizer. Then rename the ipa file to `.zip` and extract it.

From there, you'll be able to see what component is taking how much space.

This is the file structure for my app that has been extracted[image]

Comment: First i have to archive this version? @rounak

Comment: @siddle yes you'll have to archive it

Comment: After that just manually change its extension to .zip? @rounak

Comment: @siddle yep! and then extract it